# NoReverseMatchat /

Tags: django

I've got this problem. When I comes to home I get NoReverseMatch at /. Please help.

After I get this I went back to my old code (before I done it) but I still get it.
My app urls.py

```
# urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', v.index, name='index'),
        ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My views.py

```
def index(request):
    # posts = Post.objects.filter(published=True).order_by('-pub_date')[0:3]

    return render(request, 'index.html',) # add {'post': posts}
```

Here is my base_post template

```
<!--base_post template-->
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div id="highlight" class="article-clean">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-xl-8 offset-lg-1 offset-xl-2">
                <div class="intro">
                    <h1 class="text-center">{{ post.title }}<br></h1>
                    <p class="text-center">
                        <span class="by">opublikowane przez</span>
                        <a href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>
                        <span class="date">{{ post.published_date }}</span>
                    </p>
                    <img class="img-fluid" style="width=100%, height=auto" src="{{post.image.url}}">
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <p>
                        {% autoescape off %}
                            {{ post.text }}
                        {% endautoescape %}
                    </p>
                </div>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <hr>
                <nav class="blog-pagination">
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="{% url 'base_comment' pk=post.pk %}">Comment</a>
                </nav>
                {% endif %}
                <hr>
                <div class="comments">
                {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
                  <div class="comment">
                    <h4>{{ comment.author }}</h4>
                    <p>{{ comment.text }}</p>
                  </div>
                  {% empty %}
                  <p>No comments...</p>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

I know why post are working but home/index page in not

Comment: The problem is (likely) located in you `'index.html'` template.

Comment: but check it Reverse for 'base_post' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: yes, that is frequently generated by a `{% url ... %}` template tag.

Comment: Can you check url tags because i dont see any wrong template tags